# The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I get an error `AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidRequest The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.` when I try upload file to S3 bucket in new Frankfurt region. All works properly with `US Standard` region.

Script:

```
backup_file = '/media/db-backup_for_dev/2014-10-23_02-00-07/slave_dump.sql.gz'
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
    access_key_id:     AMAZONS3['access_key_id'],
    secret_access_key: AMAZONS3['secret_access_key']
)

s3_bucket = s3.buckets['test-frankfurt']

# Folder and file name
s3_name = "database-backups-last20days/#{File.basename(File.dirname(backup_file))}_#{File.basename(backup_file)}"

file_obj = s3_bucket.objects[s3_name]
file_obj.write(file: backup_file)
```

aws-sdk (1.56.0)

How to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: This answer solved my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483795/cant-access-s3-pre-signed-url-due-to-authorization/34495454#34495454

Comment: You have to tell the boto3 client which region you are, so      
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'eu-west-2')

Answer (score 178, accepted):

AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, also known as Signature Version 4, ("V4") is one of two authentication schemes supported by S3.

All regions support V4, but US-Standard¹, and many -- but not all -- other regions, also support the other, older scheme, Signature Version 2 ("V2").

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html ... new S3 regions deployed after January, 2014 will only support V4.

Since Frankfurt was introduced late in 2014, it does not support V2, which is what this error suggests you are using.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html explains how to enable V4 in the various SDKs, assuming you are using an SDK that has that capability.

I would speculate that some older versions of the SDKs might not support this option, so if the above doesn't help, you may need a newer release of the SDK you are using.

---

¹`US Standard` is the former name for the S3 regional deployment that is based in the `us-east-1` region. Since the time this answer was originally written,
[*"Amazon S3 renamed the US Standard Region to the US East (N. Virginia) Region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)  For all practical purposes, it's only a change in naming.

Comment: This stumps s3cmd-1.5.0-0.alpha3.fc20.noarch which comes with Fedora 20. And apparently also [stumps 1.5.0-rc1](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/402), the latest for now.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer that seems right.  It looks like the s3cmd developers don't have `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` implemented yet:  https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/402

Comment: @"Michael - sqlbot" well I switched to "awscli" for now. For those in a hurry: yum install python-pip; pip install awscli; aws configure; aws --region=eu-central-1 s3 ls s3://$BUCKET etc...

Comment: aws-sdk v2 seems to support AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 "V4" authentication nicely (related [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/664))

Comment: thnx.. this is useful for me

Comment: Here's a timeline of when AWS launched various regions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Amazon_Web_Services

Comment: Hi Team,

I got this error when i tried to check the url of image uploaded at (FYI image is getting uploaaded at S3):

<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>YCT51WGVSMR4CN3Z</RequestId>
<HostId>7DUeGfut0CZbYtXeGdN4xMcqgIzA4JfRu2RrciQFGSGURH08AcBNBNJdQI/YPdMxKCjNHal85x8=</HostId>
</Error>

aws-sdk used : 2.903.0
Node.js tech
Region : eu-west-3

Tried : aws configure set profile.<your_profile_name>.s3.signature_version s3v4

Can you please help?

Answer (score 89):

With node, try

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3( {
    endpoint: 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'eu-central-1'
} );
```

Answer (score 42):

For people using `boto3` (`Python SDK`) use the below code

```
from botocore.client import Config


s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxx',
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
```

Comment: I get error `AuthorizationQueryParametersErrorError parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'us-east-2`
 So I added `region_name='us-east-2' ` to the above code

Answer (score 41):

You should set `signatureVersion: 'v4'` in `config` to use new sign version:

```
AWS.config.update({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
```

Works for `JS` sdk.

Comment: Saved my day! Not sure why this option isn't more publicized

Answer (score 36):

I have been using Django, and I had to add these extra config variables to make this work.  (in addition to settings mentioned in https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html).

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"
```

Or previous to boto3 version 1.4.4:

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"

AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
```

Comment: still the best answer for people using boto, Thanks <3

Comment: exactly what I need

Answer (score 15):

Similar issue with the PHP SDK, this works:

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array('key'=>YOUR_AWS_KEY, 'secret'=>YOUR_AWS_SECRET, 'signature' => 'v4', 'region'=>'eu-central-1'));
```

The important bit is the `signature` and the `region`

Comment: Is region required to be specified ?

Answer (score 9):

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"

AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
```

this also saved my time after surfing for 24Hours..

Comment: This works great, you just have to change the region name to suit yours if its not "ap-south-1"

Comment: No coding changes necessary!  Set these two env vars and boto will work all right

Answer (score 8):

Code for Flask (boto3)

Don't forget to import Config. Also If you have your own config class, then change its name.

```
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),region_name=app.config["AWS_REGION"],aws_access_key_id=app.config['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], aws_secret_access_key=app.config['AWS_SECRET_KEY'])
s3.upload_fileobj(file,app.config["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"],file.filename)
url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket':app.config["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"] , 'Key': file.filename}, ExpiresIn = 10000)
```

Comment: Yes. It's also worked in django, but still not able to understand without config and region it's working fine locally, but not able to run same in aws hosting server.

Comment: @iampritamraj Boto3 looks at various configuration locations until it finds configuration values. Boto3 adheres to the following lookup order when searching through sources for configuration values:

A Config object that’s created and passed as the config parameter when creating a client
Environment variables
The ~/.aws/config file

Answer (score 3):

In Java I had to set a property

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENFORCE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")
```

and add the region to the s3Client instance.

```
s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1))
```

Answer (score 3):

With boto3, this is the code :

```
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

or

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

Comment: you have s3_client twice ?

Answer (score 3):

Supernova answer for django/boto3/django-storages worked with me:

> AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"

> Or previous to boto3 version 1.4.4:

> AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"

> AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"

just add them to your settings.py and change region code accordingly

you can check aws regions from:
[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html)

Answer (score 2):

For thumbor-aws, that used boto config, i needed to put this to the `$AWS_CONFIG_FILE`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = (your ID)
aws_secret_access_key = (your secret key)
s3 =
    signature_version = s3
```

So anything that used boto directly without changes, this may be useful

Answer (score 1):

For Android SDK, setEndpoint solves the problem, although it's been deprecated.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context, "identityPoolId", Regions.US_EAST_1);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
s3.setEndpoint("s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error was because I was using old version of aws-sdk and I updated the version so this error occured.

in my case with node js i was using `signatureVersion` in parmas object like this :

```
const AWS_S3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
  }
});
```

Then I put signature out of params object and worked like charm :

```
const AWS_S3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
  },
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your AWS S3 Bucket **Region** and Pass proper Region in Connection Request.

In My Senario I have set '**APSouth1**' for **Asia Pacific (Mumbai)**

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.APSouth1))
{
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50),
    };
    urlString = client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Boto3 , use this code.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config


s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
        aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx',
        aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxx',
        region_name='us-south-1',
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the request type was wrong. I was using GET(dumb) It must be PUT.

Comment: Saved my day, in my case I was using POST.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I used with Python

```
def uploadFileToS3(filePath, s3FileName):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', 
                    endpoint_url=settings.BUCKET_ENDPOINT_URL,
                    aws_access_key_id=settings.BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                    aws_secret_access_key=settings.BUCKET_SECRET_KEY,
                    region_name=settings.BUCKET_REGION_NAME
                    )
    try:
        s3.upload_file(
            filePath, 
            settings.BUCKET_NAME, 
            s3FileName
            )

        # remove file from local to free up space
        os.remove(filePath)

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('uploadFileToS3@Error')
        logger.error(e)
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the default version will not update. Add this command

```
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
```

in `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  endpoint: 's3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',       // Bucket region
  accessKeyId: 'A-----------------U',
  secretAccessKey: 'k------ja----------------soGp',
  Bucket: 'bucket_name',
  useAccelerateEndpoint: true,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: 'ap-south-1'             // Bucket region
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck for 3 days and finally, after reading a ton of blogs and answers I was able to configure Amazon AWS S3 Bucket.

**On the AWS Side**

*I am assuming you have already*

1. Created an s3-bucket
2. Created a user in IAM

**Steps**

1. Configure CORS settings

   you bucket > permissions > CORS configuration

   ````
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>```
   ````
2. Generate A bucket policy

your bucket > permissions > bucket policy

It should be similar to this one

```
 {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "Policy1602480700663",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Sid": "Stmt1602480694902",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": "*",
             "Action": "s3:GetObject",
             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::harshit-portfolio-bucket/*"
         }
     ]
 }
```

```
PS: Bucket policy should say `public` after this
```

3. Configure Access Control List

your bucket > permissions > acces control list

give public access

PS: Access Control List should say `public` after this

4. Unblock public Access

your bucket > permissions > Block Public Access

Edit and turn all options Off

**On a side note if you are working on django
add the following lines to you `settings.py` file of your project
**

```
#S3 BUCKETS CONFIG

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****not to be shared*****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****not to be shared******'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your-bucket-name'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# look for files first in aws 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# In India these settings work
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also coming from: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

For me this was the solution:

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-central-1"
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = 'virtual'
```

This needs to be added to settings.py in your Django project

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP SDK Follow Below.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;


$client = S3Client::factory(
    array(
        'signature' => 'v4',
        'region' => 'me-south-1',
        'key'    => YOUR_AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => YOUR_AWS_SECRET
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nodejs

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
});
var s3 = new aws.S3({
    signatureVersion: "v4",
});
let data = await s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {
        ContentType: mimeType, //image mime type from request
        Bucket: "MybucketName",
        Key: folder_name + "/" + uuidv4() + "." + mime.extension(mimeType),
        Expires: 300,
    });
  console.log(data);
```

> AWS S3 Bucket Permission Configuration

```
Deselect Block All Public Access

Add Below Policy
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
  "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
    "Effect":"Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
  "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::MybucketName/*"
  ]
  }
]
}
```

Then Paste the returned URL and make PUT request on the URL with binary file of image

Answer (score 0):

In Django, if you are using s3 for your static files,

```
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "your-bucket-region-name-here"
```

Answer (score -1):

Full working nodejs version:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3( {
    endpoint: 's3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'eu-west-2'
} );


const getPreSignedUrl = async () => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'some-bucket-name/some-folder',
        Key: 'some-filename.json',
        Expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    };
    try {
        const presignedUrl = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(url);
            });
        });
        console.log(presignedUrl);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};

getPreSignedUrl();
```