# Does Ingenieux beanstalk plugin support AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the [Beanstalk Maven Plugin](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/), v1.3.5, to deploy WAR files onto m Elastic Beanstalk instances. All was well until I recently started a new AWS account, which seems to have forced me onto some new policies (previous account was about 5 years old).  Now I can no longer deploy to S3.

I get success when validate my security setup, so all is well there.

```
 mvn br.com.ingenieux:beanstalk-maven-plugin:1.1.1:show-security-credentials
```

but running:

```
mvn -X beanstalk:upload-source-bundle
```

spits out

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I've grepped the plugin code, and there is reference to AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 in there, but I don't see how to 'turn it on'.

Does anyone have beanstalk:upload-source-bundle working in the newer AWS S3 environments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26538266/156477.  I originally tried to upload to Frankfurt, one of the newer regions, but I'm having same problem with the US regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, using the [1.4.0 SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/br/com/ingenieux/beanstalk-maven-plugin/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/). The main developer says this will be turned into a release soon.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beanstalker-users/c6GeuA3NA6U for discussion on this topic.