# s3cmd put - The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload files to s3 from ec2 using s3cmd from Frankfurt or Dublin instance:

```
s3cmd put -r folder  s3://bucket
```

However, I get:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 400 (InvalidRequest): The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4) which recommends to set the config to V4 by doing:

`signatureVersion: 'v4'`

How can I do it with s3cmd command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the latest version 1.6.1

Just upgrade s3cmd the following way or any other way you might want to use.

```
pip install --upgrade
```

Comment: my version is 1.1.0-beta3, however when I run sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install s3cmd, I get s3cmd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 155 not upgraded.

Comment: You are using outdated packages or an outdated operating system. Your original question is answered, if you do not know how to use your operating system ask it in a different question.

Comment: It hasn't got to do with the OS. The linux repositories are not up to date: http://s3tools.org/download, therefore, the recommendation to upgrade will not work for that library - I will need to manually download it

Comment: I see, in that case just install it with PIP. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Region was Asia Pacific(Mumbai). Its actual region ap-south-1. Here is link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html
Also configured AWSCLI using cmd
aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4
here is link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html

Full workingCode here

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');

var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('ipxstorage/products', { accessKeyId:'Use your accesskey', secretAccesskey:'use your sck', region:'ap-south-1'});
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();
aws.config.update({ signatureVersion:'v4'});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname+'/public/');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(multipartyMiddleware);

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.files.file);
    var file = req.files.file;
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalFilename, stream).then( function(){
        console.log('File Saved...');

        res.redirect('/')
    });
});


<form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                    
                   <div class="file-field input-field">
                       <div class="btn"><span>Browse File</span><input name="file" type="file"></div>
                       <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                           <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                       </div>

                   </div>                    
                   <button class="btn" type="Submit">Submit</button>
               </form>
```

Comment: Also configuredaws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4