# how to change AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 at datastage 11.3.1.2

Tags: amazon-s3, upload, datastage

how to change AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 at datastage?

Datastage sever version is 11.3.1 on CentOS 6.6.

Hi guys!
I try to upload file to Amazon S3, using IBM Datastage.
But I met this error.

```
T_BUCKET: Exception occurred: java.lang.Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 6D8FB525A9E21FA3, AWS Error Code: InvalidRequest, AWS Error Message: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
    at com.ibm.iis.cc.s3.impl.AmazonS3DriverImpl.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3DriverImpl.java:255)
    at com.ibm.iis.cc.cloud.CloudStage.initialize(CloudStage.java:534)
    at com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.connector.CC_JavaAdapter.initializeProcessor(CC_JavaAdapter.java:1028)
    at com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.connector.CC_JavaAdapter.getSerializedData(CC_JavaAdapter.java:702)
```

The point is Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
I found some reson

[The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4)

Now I know need to change from scheme V2 to V4. But how?
I thought maybe 11.5 version can do this. I'm trying to set up server 11.5,and I know it's not...

Comment: I don't know why using Datastage, but my boss want it... :(
Datastage dose not fit at this ..

Comment: This question about Korea and I asking to IBM. If something solved, I'll comment that.

Comment: This is just a guess from reading the link and documentation. But I'm guessing that you need to put signature = 'V4' in the configuration file (last entry in the link has this in for PHP)