# How do I use Signature Version 4 in ordinary AWS CLI calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-iam, aws-regions

Simple AWS CLI commands like `aws ec2 describe-images --region $REGION` produce the error
`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials` when `REGION` is one of af-south-1, ap-east-1, eu-south-1, or me-south-1.

[This StackOverflow  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873157/) says that newer regions only support Signature Version 4. How do I choose this in my AWS CLI (v.  2.4.15)? [This says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) that that happens automatically, but clearly it does not.

Note that this occurs whether I have this ~/.aws/config file`  or it is missing:

```
region = us-east-1
output = json
cli_pager=
```

Comment: Do you have a configured default/named profile on the machine where you triggered the aws cli command?

Comment: `cat ~/.aws/config` shows just this (I also put this in the body): `[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
cli_pager=`

Comment: Just tried testing it with at least 4 profiles in my side. It does work on my main region but not on `af-south-1` even after an AWS CLI upgrade

Comment: Thank you. For me, deleting `~/.aws/config` makes no difference to this.

Comment: Wow! let me know how do you solve the issue bro.

Comment: Hey bro, can you try the stuff in this link: https://bobcares.com/blog/aws-was-not-able-to-validate-the-provided-access-credentials-how-to-fix/

Comment: I am having trouble with that. It says "(a) Obtain tokens from a Regional endpoint(b) Change Region compatibility of session tokens for global endpoint" but I know now to do neither. It mentions setting the clock, but both commands fail on Mac. It mentions the `.boto` file but I have no such file. It also mentions the AWS config, but we already considered that.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is simply wrong: What it states was (in my case)  not the  source of the problem.

[The answer is](https://repost.aws/questions/QUI7bFygxaRtmUomTmHIJcyw/how-do-i-use-signature-version-4-in-ordinary-aws-cli-calls) that the regions [must be enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment.html#manage-account-payment-enable-disable-regions)

After you enable the region, you will see a message telling you to change settings for STS tokens under IAM Settings, enabling global tokens for all regions including these non-default regions.

Comment: And, per the AWS console page when first attempting to access a hitherto-disabled region: "When you enable access, AWS performs actions to prepare your account in that region, such as distributing your IAM resources to the region." which is perhaps why it presents as a credentials validation error.

Comment: WOW that's super good to know