# Android Amazon S3 TransferUtility

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to amazon (AWS SDK 2.3.0) s3 by using the following code

```
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "XXXXXXX",
            // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, this.
            getApplicationContext());

    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload("testbucketzzzz", "test.jpg",
            file);
```

Everytime I try to upload an Image i get the following error

> UploadTask: Failed to upload: 37 due to The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequest; Request ID: 9787E53737D02BA7)

I thought this would only be an issue with older versions of the AWS SDK. After countless hours of trying to fix it I found the following "trick" but this just leads me to another error and shouldn't be needed at all.

```
        System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
```

Comment: Well I figured out what was causing the problem, my bucket was located in Frankfurt, I just tried tested it with another bucket in Ireland which worked flawless thats atleast a fix for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload an Image to `Amazon S3` with the following snipet (make sure you are **NOT doing** this in `MainThread`):

```
    BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
          ACCESS_KEY,
          SECRET_KEY
      );
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials);
      s3Client.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);
      s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));;
    PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME", "YOUR_KEY", file);
    }
    s3Client.putObject(por);
```

If you want more information on why your approach wont work you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4/26538266)

Comment: I thought it is recommended to use CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider and not hardcore credentials anymore?

Comment: Why did you marked this answer as the right one?