# amazon s3 rest api error

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make a Http request to amazon s3(get a file) but I am getting a forbidden error.

Here is my code:

```
string today = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd,' 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'zz00", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
string bucket = "rethymno";
string path = "/aasdf.txt";
string stringToSign = "GET" +
                      "\n" +
                      "\n" +
                      "\n" +
                      today + "\n"+ 
                      "/" + bucket + path;

string AWSSecret = "xxx";
string AWSKey = "xxx";
Encoding ae = new UTF8Encoding();
HMACSHA1 signature = new HMACSHA1(ae.GetBytes(AWSSecret));
string encodedCanonical = Convert.ToBase64String(signature.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
string authHeader = "AWS " + AWSKey + ":" + encodedCanonical;
string url = "http://"+bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com"+path;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", today);

HttpWebResponse res = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

any suggestions fixing this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure your signature generation is correct and that your secret and key grant access to the resource? Have you tried doing what you're doing with the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or through the [AWS SDK for .net](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)?

Comment: It is strongly advised that you use the SDKs whenever possible. The SDKs will handle the request signing for you. This will be much less error prone.

Comment: i used the SDK for testing and everything worked fine. I must use rest api for my solution. Is there any examples of signature generation? i searched  amazon documentation but i came up to this code above.

Comment: You say it's a `Forbidden` error... but what does the XML in the response body look like?  S3 errors are usually pretty informative.

Comment: i cant get an s3 error since its an http request. Am i wrong?

Comment: The HTTP request should return an XML block that describes the problem if you're getting errors.

Comment: wkl is correct there should be an error message returned in the content of the response. It wil be in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the signature works:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Read through the steps here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Things to pay attention to:
- signing algorithm (SHA1 or SHA256). I don't see in passed in the headers for you
- time on your computer. make sure the time and the tz is correct or the signing will fail 
- the request is in a canonical form (the right string stripping / substitutions happen). The parameters are sorted
- you specify the signature version + you use the right date. see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html (does not look like you are doing the right things).

As other comments say: when given the choice use the SDK or for the language you are using find an example someone already has working.

Comment: The code above is [Signature Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html).  At first glance it looks pretty close. Not all regions support Sig V2 but there's a [specific error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26538266/1695906) for that condition.

Comment: still cant make it work. i changed the code. i woud appreciate it if you could take a look on the newest post.