# AWS SDK for .NET. The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I received the next error while sending the ListObjectRequest:

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4) answer, `AmazonS3Config` was updated in the following way:

```
var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    SignatureVersion = "4",
    ServiceURL = bucketName,
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
    SignatureMethod = SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256
};

var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretKey, amazonS3Config);
```

But I still receive this error. What have I missed here?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using Frankfurt and my code is exactly as yours which works. Just hazarding a guess... Maybe USEast1 supports SignatureVersion 3 or below only?

Comment: I tried to use different signature versions (4, 3, 2)  to check if it works with anyone. But it fails.

Comment: Can you try Frankfurt. Same code works for.me on Frankfurt so ne reason it shouldn't work for you..otherwise there's more to this issue than we can see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the last version of amazonS3 sdk.I think ServiceUrl is not necessary  when you know regionEndpoint, I used it with private cloud amazonS3 and When  I do not know the Region Endpoint. I can retrieve the information from Amazon using the following code.

```
        var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config();
        // region of FrankPurt is : RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1
        // according to amazonS3 Doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region
        amazonS3Config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key", "your secret key", amazonS3Config);
         S3DirectoryInfo dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "your bucket name", "your folder path without bucket name");
        Console.WriteLine(dir.GetFiles().Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using this I am able to work in EU west 2 region

```
            AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
            config.SignatureVersion = "4";
            config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-west-2");
            config.SignatureMethod = Amazon.Runtime.SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256;
```

region should