# Getting "Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)" error for asset_sync gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am trying to set up existing rails 3.2.11 project in production environment.

We have used asset_sync gem for syncing assets in s3. But when I ran the precompile command I am getting **Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)** error. As per the documentation I have added required configuration in the file (application.yml file).

```
production:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: xxxxxx
  FOG_PROVIDER: xxxxxx
  FOG_REGION: xxxxxx
  ASYNC_UPLOAD_BUCKET: xxxxxx
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: xxxxxx
  AWS_BUCKET: xxxxxx
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: xxxxxx
```

As per the doc created separate initializer file (config/initializers/asset_sync.rb)

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'AWS'
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.fog_region = ENV['FOG_REGION']
end
```

When I checked the response for the compilation it is showing message

```
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
```

Can any one let me know how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using the yegor256/s3auth auth gateway by any chance?

Comment: How can I check the auth getway. Also I haven't configured any getway.

Comment: I wonder if it is a good idea to deploy a Rails 3.2.11 app to production? That version is more than 4 years old, unmaintained and has known security issues. The issue you face is probably related to having a version of the `aws` gem in your `Gemfile` that is too old too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4

Comment: @spickermann I tired by passing signatureVersion but getting the same issue. I tired this way `Aws.config.update(signatureVersion: 'v4')` Is there any other suggestion.