# AWS create cluster running into error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr

New to AWS. The below job is running into error. Please help

`mrjob create-cluster --instance-type m1.medium --region us-east-1 --num-core-instances 3`

Trace:

> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 817, in
>   _set_cloud_tmp_dir
>       if (tmp_bucket.get_location() == s3_location_constraint_for_region(   File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 1146, in
>   get_location
>       response.status, response.reason, body) error: boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request 
>   `InvalidRequest`The authorization mechanism
>   you have provided is not supported. Please use
>   AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.AFAFB32563D25847nQrsnGiNfsvYpDYxIWKlvOCWEp5VPuPm2mEkKuDvb29+SpRCjs029CYTx3SjHEQJH5zuYB9XUUo=

Comment: All the needed info is in your error response already: you possibly use wrong auth mechanism for this job

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4

Comment: Thanks for the support guys. :).I had changed the region and s3 had some buckets from the previous region.After deleting those buckets it started working fine.