# Why a client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation via aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

Now Im trying to backup my database via aws cli but it throws following error

```
root@f22e9806cb38:~# aws s3 sync $BACKUP_PATH $S3_URL
A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
root@f22e9806cb38:~# aws --version
aws-cli/1.4.2 Python/3.4.2 Linux/4.13.0-31-generic
```

I've configured aws cli with `aws configure` command and pasted access and private keys. How to fix the error?

Comment: Quite possibly your version of aws-cli is too old, compared to the region where your bucket is... 1.4.2 is from 2014, and only regions where S3 was first launched in 2014 or later would return this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538266/1695906).

Comment: Ur awesome. Could you leave the answer?

Comment: I assume that upgrading aws-cli solved the problem, then?

Comment: Yes, I installed it by pip instead of apt and it gave me the latest version (I dont know why apt have such old version in repos)