# boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

**I am getting this error to access S3 bucket. My region is mumbai.**

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
>   
>   `InvalidRequest`The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. 
>   Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.7BD86CC040523574I1zzUtAgjBS0dOUo/mP/Z7uei/l+f8YXEdlqeu1N+7mXrHV9IwYxWBLkx1E/y4DNm6QzPdyRihE=

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4

Comment: thank you so much @MahbuburRahman

Answer (score 2):

Try by providing the host name corresponding to the S3 bucket region.
For example:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, host='s3.us-east- 2.amazonaws.com')
```

Comment: this solved my issue with some legacy code that 'used to' work just fine 4 years ago. since then i've noticed AWS changing around their bucket region and SLD (second level domain) formatting... so maybe being more specific with this param is now required? note: i'm using boto v2.49 now; but i can't verify what i was using 4 years ago