# Signature error preventing upload to S3 bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, openssl

I'm trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket using the curl command. I'm using the following set of commands. I need the host name to be in the format `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/` instead of `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` because the bucket has periods in it (unfortunately the bucket name is out of my control).

```
file=$(pwd)/test.txt
bucket=bucket_name
resource="/s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -o -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${file}
```

But I keep getting the following error in response.

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>
```

Answer (score 0):

the authorization method you are using are no longer supported try the script below

```
#!/bin/sh

usage()
{
    cat <<USAGE

Simple script uploading a file to S3. Supports AWS signature version 4, custom
region, permissions and mime-types. Uses Content-MD5 header to guarantee
uncorrupted file transfer.

Usage:
  `basename $0` aws_ak aws_sk bucket srcfile targfile [acl] [mime_type]

Where <arg> is one of:
  aws_ak     access key ('' for upload to public writable bucket)
  aws_sk     secret key ('' for upload to public writable bucket)
  bucket     bucket name (with optional @region suffix, default is us-east-1)
  srcfile    path to source file
  targfile   path to target (dir if it ends with '/', relative to bucket root)
  acl        s3 access permissions (default: public-read)
  mime_type  optional mime-type (tries to guess if omitted)

Dependencies:
  To run, this shell script depends on command-line curl and openssl, as well
  as standard Unix tools

Examples:
  To upload file '~/blog/media/image.png' to bucket 'storage' in region
  'eu-central-1' with key (path relative to bucket) 'media/image.png':

    `basename $0` ACCESS SECRET storage@eu-central-1 \\
      ~/blog/image.png media/

  To upload file '~/blog/media/image.png' to public-writable bucket 'storage'
  in default region 'us-east-1' with key (path relative to bucket) 'x/y.png':

    `basename $0` '' '' storage ~/blog/image.png x/y.png

USAGE
    exit 0
}

guessmime()
{
    mime=`file -b --mime-type $1`
    if [ "$mime" = "text/plain" ]; then
        case $1 in
            *.css)           mime=text/css;;
            *.ttf|*.otf)     mime=application/font-sfnt;;
            *.woff)          mime=application/font-woff;;
            *.woff2)         mime=font/woff2;;
            *rss*.xml|*.rss) mime=application/rss+xml;;
            *)               if head $1 | grep '<html.*>' >/dev/null; then mime=text/html; fi;;
        esac
    fi
    printf "$mime"
}

if [ $# -lt 5 ]; then usage; fi

# Inputs.
aws_ak="$1"                                                              # access key
aws_sk="$2"                                                              # secret key
bucket=`printf $3 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="@"}{print $1}'`                       # bucket name
region=`printf $3 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="@"}{print ($2==""?"us-east-1":$2)}'`  # region name
srcfile="$4"                                                             # source file
targfile=`echo -n "$5" | sed "s/\/$/\/$(basename $srcfile)/"`            # target file
acl=${6:-'public-read'}                                                  # s3 perms
mime=${7:-"`guessmime "$srcfile"`"}                                      # mime type
md5=`openssl md5 -binary "$srcfile" | openssl base64`


# Create signature if not public upload.
key_and_sig_args=''
if [ "$aws_ak" != "" ] && [ "$aws_sk" != "" ]; then

    # Need current and file upload expiration date. Handle GNU and BSD date command style to get tomorrow's date.
    date=`date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ`
    expdate=`if ! date -v+1d +%Y-%m-%d 2>/dev/null; then date -d tomorrow +%Y-%m-%d; fi`
    expdate_s=`printf $expdate | sed s/-//g` # without dashes, as we need both formats below
    service='s3'

    # Generate policy and sign with secret key following AWS Signature version 4, below
    p=$(cat <<POLICY | openssl base64
{ "expiration": "${expdate}T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "$acl" },
    {"bucket": "$bucket" },
    ["starts-with", "\$key", ""],
    ["starts-with", "\$content-type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 1, `ls -l -H "$srcfile" | awk '{print $5}' | head -1`],
    {"content-md5": "$md5" },
    {"x-amz-date": "$date" },
    {"x-amz-credential": "$aws_ak/$expdate_s/$region/$service/aws4_request" },
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" }
  ]
}
POLICY
    )

    # AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 signature
    s=`printf "$expdate_s"   | openssl sha256 -hmac "AWS4$aws_sk"           -hex | sed 's/(stdin)= //'`
    s=`printf "$region"      | openssl sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$s" -hex | sed 's/(stdin)= //'`
    s=`printf "$service"     | openssl sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$s" -hex | sed 's/(stdin)= //'`
    s=`printf "aws4_request" | openssl sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$s" -hex | sed 's/(stdin)= //'`
    s=`printf "$p"           | openssl sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$s" -hex | sed 's/(stdin)= //'`

    key_and_sig_args="-F X-Amz-Credential=$aws_ak/$expdate_s/$region/$service/aws4_request -F X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F X-Amz-Signature=$s -F X-Amz-Date=${date}"
fi


# Upload. Supports anonymous upload if bucket is public-writable, and keys are set to ''.
echo "Uploading: $srcfile ($mime) to $bucket:$targfile"
curl                            \
    -# -k                       \
    -F key=$targfile            \
    -F acl=$acl                 \
    $key_and_sig_args           \
    -F "Policy=$p"              \
    -F "Content-MD5=$md5"       \
    -F "Content-Type=$mime"     \
    -F "file=@$srcfile"         \
    https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/ | cat # pipe through cat so curl displays upload progress bar, *and* response
```

reference https://www.aws.ps/how-to-upload-file-to-s3-using-curl/

Comment: If this were a case of Signature V2 not being supported in the region, the error would be *The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.* https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533245/1695906

Comment: Your code may work fine, but I believe your answer is incorrect for the question being asked, since your explanation of the reason for the *Signature does not match* error is not accurate.

Comment: well, the code he had is not working anymore, even if he pasted change the signature, I provided with the supported signature method !!

Answer (score 0):

Signature Version 2 (which is what you are using, here) always expects the resource to be `/${bucket}/${file}` regardless of whether the  URL is path-based (bucket as the first element of the path) or virtual (bucket as part of the hostname).

Additionally, for legacy reasons, S3 expects `+` in the signature to be url-escaped as `%2B` and (iirc) will accept but does not require any `/` to be transformed to `%2F` and any `=` to be transformed to `%3D` so you need to verify (`curl -v ...`) whether curl is transforming it, and if not, use something like `sed` or maybe `tr` in the pipeline to do that encoding of the signature, or perhaps find a curl option that can enable the query string parameter encoding.

Be aware that [Signature V2 is deprecated](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-sigv2-deprecation-period-extended-modified/) and will be deactivated at some point after June, 2020, so even though it still works on existing buckets in regions where S3 originally launched prior to 2014, its usable lifespan is most definitely coming to an end... so your interests would be served by not creating new systems that use it.  The successor algorithm, Signature V4, is more complicated but there are solid security-related justifications for its increased complexity.